Can't figure out how to export transparency (Glass, Ice) to a gltf binary file
I need help to understand how I can export this item with same transparency, colors and reflection style in glTF binary for a GSAP website!
I'm pretty noob in blender, can someone explain me step by step what to do?


https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

While glTF supports basic materials that use the Principled BSDF node with bare values or UV mapped image textures as inputs, the final render is always up to the render engine.
So to answer your question here, the best you can do on Blender's side is to make sure your material is set up as mentioned above.
As for how the render is done in your target software, that would be out of topic on this website. But GSAP seems to use Three.js to handle 3D models, so I would refer you to that manual page that mentions alpha handling and whatnot:
Materials – three.js docs
